# how can i make left join with two condition (on Clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

when i write the below query , that message return

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

how to solve it please .

```
SELECT  PD.ProductID, PD.DesignID, PDCI.ColorID, 
        PD.TotalPrice, PD.PictureName, P.ProductTitle, 
        P.Quantity, P.Availability, P.TodayDeal,
        P.NewArrival, P.Bestseller, P.Likes, 
        P.CreatedOn, D.Name, PDCI.ColorImage
FROM [Diwan].tbProductDesigns PD    
LEFT JOIN [Diwan].tbProducts P 
       ON P.ProductID = PD.ProductID
LEFT JOIN [Design].tbDesignCover D 
       ON D.DesignID = PD.DesignID
LEFT JOIN [Diwan].tbProductDesignColorImages PDCI 
       ON PDCI.ProductID = PD.ProductID 
      AND PDCI.DesignID = PD.DesignID
WHERE PD.DesignID = 2
```

From comments: Total price is a calculated column using this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTotalProductPrice] (
  @ProductID BIGINT,
  @DesignID BIGINT
)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      SELECT P.Price + D.SellingPrice
      FROM Diwan.tbProductDesigns PD
      LEFT JOIN Diwan.tbProducts P ON PD.ProductID = P.ProductID
      LEFT JOIN Design.tbDesignCover D ON PD.DesignID = D.DesignID
      WHERE PD.ProductID = @ProductID
        AND PD.DesignID = @DesignID
      )
END
```

Comment: Your query has no subquery.  Hence, the error statement seems very, very unlikely.

Comment: Are any of those objects you're selecting from a view, or are you leaving out part of your query?

Comment: The code you posted won't give that error. Except if there are any calculated columns in play, or any of the sources have code hidden in views.

Comment: column totalprice is a computed column, use function in that column .
this is the reason ?

Comment: Yes that could cause it.

Comment: how can solve it or what the best query to avoid computed column in my query ?

Comment: Show us the function.

Comment: * represent at as avariable

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTotalProductPrice]
(
 *ProductID bigint ,
 *DesignID bigint
 )

RETURNS money
 
as

begin
return
(
select P.Price+D.SellingPrice
from Diwan.tbProductDesigns PD 
left join Diwan.tbProducts P on PD.ProductID=P.ProductID
left join Design.tbDesignCover D on PD.DesignID=D.DesignID
where PD.ProductID=*ProductID and PD.DesignID=*DesignID
)
end

Comment: If that function can return more than one row, either fix it so that it doesn't or maybe use sum() for the price. You do know that you're calculating something in outer join that can be null?

Comment: best thing to do will be to get rid of that computed column and function entirely. It will kill performance.

Comment: yes it return only one row , but using  addtion to two column from different tables .

Comment: how to can solve that problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why the function is necessary:

```
SELECT  PD.ProductID, PD.DesignID, PDCI.ColorID, 
        (P.Price + D.SellingPrice) AS TotalPrice, PD.PictureName, P.ProductTitle, 
        P.Quantity, P.Availability, P.TodayDeal,
        P.NewArrival, P.Bestseller, P.Likes, 
        P.CreatedOn, D.Name, PDCI.ColorImage
FROM [Diwan].tbProductDesigns PD    
LEFT JOIN [Diwan].tbProducts P 
       ON P.ProductID = PD.ProductID
LEFT JOIN [Design].tbDesignCover D 
       ON D.DesignID = PD.DesignID
LEFT JOIN [Diwan].tbProductDesignColorImages PDCI 
       ON PDCI.ProductID = PD.ProductID 
      AND PDCI.DesignID = PD.DesignID
WHERE PD.DesignID = 2
```

Comment: Totalprice is computed column ,and want it to be inserted automaticly

Comment: Inserted where?  And are you saying this doesn't return the correct value for `TotalPrice`?